# Ряд суммы обратных квадратов на java

Tags: java, математика, ряды

**Здравствуйте!**

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.
Хочу написать программу на java которая считает сумму обратных квадратов для определеного количества членов. Код прилагается.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=1;
        float[] members;
        members = new float[11];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            members[i] = 1/n*n;
            n++;
            if (i == 9) {
                float sum = 0;
                for (int a = 0; a < members.length; a++) {
                    sum = sum + members[a];
                }
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

В итоге консоль выдет пустую строку.

Comment: сейчас напишу ответ

Comment: Первая проблема - математические операции с одинаковым приоритетом выполняются последовательно слева направо, поэтому с математической точки зрения `1/n*n` = `(1/n)*n`. С точки зрения математики, это выражения всегда будет равно единице. Вторая проблема - `int/int => int`, итоговое выражение деления будет приводится к результату integer. Поэтому при приведении вы будете всегда терять дробную часть и получать в итоге `0.0`. Будьте внимательны при делении, один из вариантов в делении добавить float: `members[i] = 1f/(n*n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Главное

- Результат деления может приводиться к целому числу из-за того что слева и справа от оператора деления находятся целые числа
- Как верно заметил @AlexKrass в комментариях важна последовательность выполнения операций, поэтому вам следовало бы сгруппировать возведение в квадрат в скобки или использовать `Math.pow()`

#### Другие замечания

- во-первых строка не пустая: у меня выводится `1.0`
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- мне кажется что в данном случае будет уместнее использовать `double`, а не `float`
- вы

  - определяете массив с 11 элементами
  - заполняете 10 элементов
  - считаете сумму для 11
- считаете сумму внутри цикла, который заполняет ряд
  не надо так делать, просто цикл с подсчетом суммы и разместите его сразу после заполнения
- если Вам нужна только сумма - заполнение массива будет лишним.
  лишний код, лишняя память, лишние действия

#### Решение

```java
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumOfInverseSquares(10));
    }
    
    public static double sumOfInverseSquares(int size) {
        double result = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            result = result + 1 / Math.pow(i, 2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

output:

```
1.5397677311665408
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Innoky, не за что) Удачи Вам в освоении программирования)